# Which device the reset vector address is mapped?

Tags: linux, memory, x86

```
#cat /proc/iomem
          .

          .

          .

**000f0000-000fffff : System ROM**
          .

          .

          .

**fffe0000-ffffffff : reserved**
```

But Intel Reference Manual says that the reset vector address starts from 0xfffffff0 . According to my understanding the ROM is mapped to the reset vector address but here the reset vector address is in the reserved range
can anyone please explain this context .

```
#uname -a
Linux sakthivel 4.2.0-34-generic #39~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:39:00 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

The System Rom Address space is a legacy of the PC origins of running on an Intel 8088 which was a 16bit processor with a 20 bit address space, which had the reset vector at `0xffff0`.  There is a good description of how that legacy manifests itself on more modern hardware [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806129/7311767)